# How to check if the length of a string is more than one word and keep only the first word else keep the entire string in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, string-length

I have the following table in sql.

[image]

I want to keep only the first word in the Name column. I have written the code below however when I run it it extracts the first word for strings longer that one word but returns empty cell for strings which consist of one word only. Could you please advise me how should I modify it to achieve the desired result of keeping only the first word of all strings.

SELECT ID,substr(Name, 1, instr ( Name, ' ' ) -1 ) AS Name FROM names_list

DBMS Toad for Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `regexp_substr()`?

```
select regexp_substr(name, '^[^ ]+')
from names_list;
```

This is more flexible than `instr()`, because you have more control over the separators.  For instance, if a comma is sometimes used as well:

```
select regexp_substr(name, '^[^ ,]+')
from names_list;
```

Answer (score 1):

This would select the first *word* out of the `name` column:

```
SQL> with names_list (id, name) as
  2    (select 1, 'John Smith'          from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'One'                 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Nikola O''Neil'      from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Rose Ann Lee'        from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Neil'                from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'William Hugh Forest' from dual union all
  8     select 7, 'Andrew'              from dual
  9    )
 10  select id,
 11    regexp_substr(name, '^\w+') name
 12  from names_list;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 John
         2 One
         3 Nikola
         4 Rose
         5 Neil
         6 William
         7 Andrew

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```